# Internal Server Error when running sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sqlsrv

```
<?php
$ls_query = "select * from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID, col1 from table where col1 = 'xxxxx') as temp where RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10 order by col1";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $ls_query);
$no_of_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
echo $no_of_rows;
?>
```

When executing this script I get (after 30 seconds):

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

While when executing the query in SQL Server it takes 1 minute to run but give results.

decreasing or increasing max_execution_time in php.ini makes no effect.
If i change max_execution_time to 2.
It still gives same error in 30 secs

Comment: Is your .htaccess file perfect ?

Comment: In your project folder or root folder. Just press control + h to find the .htaccess folder

Comment: That might just simply be your PHP script dying because the `max_execution_time` (which coincidentally has a default value of 30 seconds) has been exceeded.

Comment: I have used set_time_limit(0); on top of script

Comment: increased max_execution_time to 150 from php.ini

Comment: @VipinSoni Does this query return so many results? 1 minute is very long time for few results, try adding `with (nolock)` keywords after table names in your query.

Comment: no it returns only 4 rows, adding with (nolock) give same error.

Comment: I suggest you to log sqlsrv errors.Add this line after `sqlsrv_query(...)`: `error_log(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));`.Or just print them onto screen, but comment last two lines.

Comment: same error, It not reaches that line.